# coded user interface test not same behavior on different PC

Tags: c#, visual-studio, coded-ui-tests

I'm new on coded user interface test on visual studio, so I tried some tests.
I generated a test on my PC, and I replayed this test on two other machines.

One of the machine fails the test:

> Message : Test method CodedUITest.CodedUITest1.LoadDataProcessing
>   threw exception:
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestControlNotFoundException:
>   The playback failed to find the control with the given search
>   properties. Additional Details: TechnologyName:  'MSAA'ControlType: 
>   'MenuItem'Name:  'Data Processing...' --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

The test doesn't open the tool strip menu item, and so the "data processing" MenuItem is not visible.

The three PC use Visual Studio 2017 Entreprise, and I checked: all are up-to-date with CUIT installed. The only different what I see, it's the PC is on Windows 10 and all other run on Windows 7. Is it Windows version ? And how to solve this issue ?

Other info: CUIT is done on EXE application.

Comment: As far as I know, the CUIT reads the controls from your UI. If your test expects to find that "data processing" MenuItem on your UI, it will fail with the error message you provided. Debugging the test in vs on the machine that failed that test could provide you with more info on why it does not open that tool strip menu item.

Comment: You could also try to open that tool strip menu item from within your test, if the menuItem isn't found. Do this by using Mouse.click(yourControl); .

Comment: the test doesn't find "data processing" menuItem because it doesn't "click" on the tool strip menu which contains this menuItem (but no error message about the tool strip menu). I will code the click manually

Comment: Let me know if that worked out for you, I'll provide my comment above as a answer so you can mark your problem as solved.
My experience with generated CUIT is that it usually needs some tweaks in the code. Nowadays, I just use the inspector to select the controls I want to include in my test, and write the test manually.

Comment: ok, as I said, I'm new in CUIT, and I find the system to take the reference of the UI not very intuitive, I will try when I back to my holidays ;)

Comment: hey, everybody needs to learn right? Have a nice holidays!